# how to copy custom attribute values from quote_address to sales_order_address table

Tags: magento2, custom, custom-attributes, customer-address-attribute

i am using some custom attributes in customer address section.The attribute values are getting in quote_address table but not getting that in sale_order_address table.
The file i used to do that field.xml

```
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
 <!--quote convert to sales-->
 <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">            
     <field name="address_label">
         <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
     </field>
     <field name="house_name">
         <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
     </field>
     <field name="locations">
         <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
     </field>
     <field name="landmark">
         <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
     </field>
 </fieldset>
</scope>
</config>
```

This file was not worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The following example is copying the quote table to the sales_order table.
You need to create a event.xml and Observer.

event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="your_module_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Your\Module\Observer\SaveToOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

SaveToOrder.php

```
class SaveToOrder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_objectCopyService;

    public function __construct(
        Copy $objectCopyService
    ) {
        $this->_objectCopyService = $objectCopyService;
    }

    /**
     * List of attributes that should be added to an order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $attributes = [
        'attributes_1',
        'attributes_2',
    ];

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote = $event->getData('quote');
        $order = $event->getData('order');

        //set attributes
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($quote->hasData($attribute)) {
            $order->setData($attribute, $quote->getData($attribute));
            }
        }

        //copy order to sale_order
        $this->_objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
            'sales_convert_quote',
            'to_order',
            $quote,
            $order
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This article may helpful for you !
https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-checkout-field/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/205913)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.